# How do I install the Visual Editor plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: macos, plugins, java, eclipse, swing

Using the two newest versions of the Eclipse IDE, I have been unsuccessful in installing the [Visual Editor for Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/vep/). When trying to install the plugin after adding the repository, I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Visual Editor 1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk (org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk)
  Missing requirement: Visual Editor Common Data Editor 1.4.0.v20090826-1446 (org.eclipse.ve.cde 1.4.0.v20090826-1446) requires 'bundle com.ibm.icu [3.4.4.1,4.1.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Visual Editor 1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk (org.eclipse.ve.feature.group 1.4.0.v20090826-1446-777N-CcNBC0BwNk5HZZk)
    To: org.eclipse.ve.cde [1.3.0,2.0.0)
```

My installation is a standard installation of the 64-bit Carbon Eclipse IDE for OS X (running 10.5.8). It would appear as though the plugin wants `com.ibm.icu` installed, but it is a part of the IDE by default (albeit a few versions ahead). Long story short, **is there any way to install the visual editor into Eclipse** (or should I just use Netbeans)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved in the most recent stable version of Eclipse (3.6.1) using VE plugin 1.5.0. It can be installed normally without error.